# JRE 1.7 and Spark version 2.6.0. having exception java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: spark/Route : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, spark-java

I am using JRE 1.7 with spark version 2.6.0 and IDE as InteliJ idea. Source of my class is as below:

```
package com.tengen;

import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;
import spark.Spark;

public class HelloWorldSparkStyle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spark.get("/",new Route() {
            @Override
            public Object handle(final Request request, final Response response) throws Exception {
                return "Hello World from Spark";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I get this exception when I try to run this class:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=4388:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\M101J\target\M101J-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.12\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.12\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.12\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.3\logback-classic-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.3\logback-core-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.14\snakeyaml-1.14.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.4.6\jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.4.6\jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.4.6\jackson-core-2.4.6.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.3.2.Final\hibernate-validator-4.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.0.CR2\jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.1.7.RELEASE\spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.1.7.RELEASE\spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.1.7.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.1.7.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.1.7.RELEASE\spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.1.7.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.1.7.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring4\2.1.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\2.1.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\3.0.8\ognl-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.0.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\nz\net\ultraq\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-layout-dialect\1.2.9\thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.2.9.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-actuator\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-legacy\1.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-legacy-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.17\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.17.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\com\github\kernel164\gmultipart\0.4\gmultipart-0.4.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.2.2\commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.0.1\commons-io-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\com\sparkjava\spark-core\2.6.0\spark-core-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.12\slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-server\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-http-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-io-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-webapp\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-xml\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-xml-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlet\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-security\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-security-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-server\9.2.11.v20150529\websocket-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-common\9.2.11.v20150529\websocket-common-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-client\9.2.11.v20150529\websocket-client-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-servlet\9.4.4.v20170414\websocket-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-api\9.4.4.v20170414\websocket-api-9.4.4.v20170414.jar;C:\Users\naeemj\.m2\repository\org\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.26-incubating\freemarker-2.3.26-incubating.jar" com.tengen.HelloWorldSparkStyle
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: spark/Route : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Exception in thread "main" 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Spark version 2.6.0?? We are only on Spark 2.2...

Answer (score 0):

you are using JRE 1.7 with spark version 2.6.0, you need to use Java 8 
you can find below the version of the JRE the class file is compatible with this:

```
Java SE 9 = 53,
Java SE 8 = 52,
Java SE 7 = 51,
Java SE 6.0 = 50,
Java SE 5.0 = 49,
```

for more you can refer below stackoverflow link Question By : ERJAN and Answer by : Many java Experts.

[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: Which spark version is supported with Java 7? I am using below dependency for spark


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @JawadNaeem There is no Spark 2.6.0. Change the version to 2.1.0 or 2.2.0.

Comment: Hi, 2.6.0 is a valid version listed on spark website at URL of sparkJava website http://sparkjava.com/download. as i mentioned dependency is given there as <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>